# Create custom option programatically in magento 1.7.0.1

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I m creating custom optoin programatically on `catalog_product_save_after` event .but the problem is when observer run it will create 3 to 4 same option instead of just create one option on save.one another problem is when there is no custom option in product it will not create any option when i create just one option manualy and then save it will work.

[image]

Observer code

```
public function createMyCustomOption(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $options = $this->getOptions('test','drop_down',8,40,1);
        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
                  ->setProductId($product->getId())
                  ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                  ->addData($options);
        try {
            $option->save();

        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit('error');
        }
        $product->addOption($option);

        //echo '<pre>';

        //print_r($options);
        //exit;
        //$productmo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        //$productmo->setProductOptions($options);
        //$productmo->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        //$productmo->setHasOptions(1)->save();
        //return;


    }

    protected  function getOptions($title = '',$type='',$for=NULL,$price=1,$isrequired = 1){

    $optionvalue = array();
        for($i=1;$i<=$for;$i++)
        {
            $optionvalue[$i]['title'] = $i;
            $optionvalue[$i]['price'] = $i*$price;
            $optionvalue[$i]['price_type'] = 'fixed';
            $optionvalue[$i]['sku'] = '';
            $optionvalue[$i]['sort_order'] = $i; 
        }
        $option = array(
                'title' => (string)$title,
                'type' => $type, // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
                'is_require' => $isrequired,
                'sort_order' => 0,
                'values' => $optionvalue
                );

        return $option;
    }
```

Comment: try this event "catalog_product_prepare_save"

Comment: and try to log data using Mage::log('your message'); so can find how many times this message logged

Comment: @Keyul Shah Thanks for your quick replay.I have logged saved entry it display only once still custom option create two to three times.

Comment: If he logged once then your observer called one time there is some mistake in code please check your code twise

Comment: yes @Marius that's the exactly i was looking for.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can try below code for the create custom option.

```
 $option = array(
    'title' => 'Your custom option title',
    'type' => 'radio', // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
    'is_require' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'values' => getOptions()
    );

function getOptions(){
   return array(
   array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 1',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 1',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    ),
array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 2',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 2',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    ),
  array(
    'title' => 'Option Value 3',
    'price' =>100,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'any sku for 3',
    'sort_order' => '1'
    )
);
}

//Suppose we are creating a new product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setProductOptions(array($option));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

//Or if we are adding the options to a already created product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setProductOptions(array($option));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

//Do not forget to save the product
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check if the product created is a new product or is an edited old product. Otherwise any change that the admin makes to a product will result in new custom options.

You could check if the `origData` is empty or something like that but a while ago I stumbled on an article about the `isObjectNew` flag which might be of use here. You can read [the article](http://ceckoslab.com/magento/check-if-object-is-new/) here.

It probably also prevents your code from being triggered multiple times when using the check.